# Is there a way to set the measurement units from Pixels to Points in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

Im reading the book Microsoft Visual C# Step by Step, Ninth Edition.
The author shows how to set the font size measure in points but, In my Visual Studio 2019 I just have the option to work in pixels. If I try to use points (pt) then it is converted to pixels. For example, 20 pt is converted to 26.667 px

Is it was an error by the author give the idea we can work with points?

**Screenshot from the IDE:**

[image: Screenshot from my IDE]

**Screenshot from the book:**

[image: Screenshot from the book]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design features provided in Visual Studio are relatively limited. It is mainly used to write XAML code.

If you want to switch the default unit, you can try `Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio`, it will also be installed when installing Visual Studio.

And the options here:

[image: Imgur]

*In Visual Studio, there is no same option*

[image: Imgur]

Best regards.